# Google Maps error on Content Security Policy

Tags: asp.net, google-maps, content-security-policy

I have the following line on the layout loading the google maps script:

```
<script src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?key=MY_KEY" async defer></script>
```

On the web.config, Content Security Policy is enabled allowing only self scripts and the *.googleapis.com

```
<content-Security-Policy enabled="true">
      <script-src self="true">
        <add source="*.googleapis.com"/>            
      </script-src>
    </content-Security-Policy>
```

When I open the page, google maps plugin is working fine. But I'm getting this error on the JavaScript console:

> js?key=MY_KEY:318 Refused to connect to 'https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/mapsjs/gen_204?csp_test=true' because it violates the following Content Security Policy directive: "connect-src 'self'".

It seems like the google script is loading a second call to that other script. (And what's that csp_test=true means??)
Even though the gmaps is working, I would like to get rid of that exception, and I'm not able to... Any help?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The script attempts to send data to maps.googleapis.com, but that is not allowed as you have restricted connect-src to 'self' only. You would likely need to add modify your configuration to this:

```
<content-Security-Policy enabled="true">
  <script-src self="true">
    <add source="*.googleapis.com"/>            
  </script-src>
  <connect-src self="true">
    <add source="*.googleapis.com"/>            
  </connect-src>
</content-Security-Policy>
```

You could also be more restrictive on the subdomain (maps.googleapis.com) or use the default-src directive instead.

Comment: That was it! Very easy solution :_) thanks a lot

Comment: @Ivan where should we add this content-Security-Policy?

Comment: @Ivan - where to set these configurations? 

In my index.html I have already allowed maps.googleapis.com in my Content-Security-Policy meta content.